# How to evaluate $\int \frac{\arctan x}{x\sqrt {1+x^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{\arctan x}{x}\right)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, indefinite-integrals

How to evaluate 
$$\int \frac{\arctan x}{x\sqrt {1+x^2}}e^{-\arctan x/x} \, dx$$

I tried using substitution $x=\tan t,dx=\sec ^2tdt,$It becomes the following：
$$\int\frac{t}{\sin t}e^{-t\cot t}dt$$

Then I got stuck，any hint of help is welcome.

Comment: i think there is no solution in the known elementary functions

Comment: Thank you.Isn't there a elementary function?

Comment: i think no try Wolfram Alpha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We guess a primitive of the form $$\int\frac{t}{\sin t}e^{-t\cot t} dt = e^{-t\cot t}u$$
where $u$ is a function of $t$.
Then $$\begin{aligned}
&t\csc t{e^{ - t\cot t}} = ({e^{ - t\cot t}}u)' = (t{\csc ^2}t - \cot t){e^{ - t\cot t}}u + {e^{ - t\cot t}}u'\\
&\iff t\csc t = (t{\csc ^2}t - \cot t)u + u'\\
&\iff t\sin t = (t - \cos t\sin t)u + u'{\sin ^2}t
\end{aligned}$$

One immediately notices that $u=\sin t $ is a solution.

Hence $$\int {\frac{t}{{\sin t}}{e^{ - t\cot t}}dt}  = {e^{ - t\cot t}}\sin t + C$$

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to prove the antiderivative listed by pisco without a guess, and so I figured out how to do so

I started with the fact that $(-t\cot t)' = \frac{t}{\sin^2 t} - \cot t$

Then we obtain
\begin{align*}
&\int \frac{t}{\sin t}e^{-t\cot t} dt\\
=&\int \sin t \left(\frac{t}{\sin^2 t} - \cot t + \cot t\right)e^{-t\cot t} dt\\
=&\int \cos t e^{-t\cot t}dt + \int \sin t\left(\frac{t}{\sin^2 t} - \cot t\right)e^{-t\cot t} dt
\end{align*}

Using integration by parts with $u=\sin t$ and $dv = \left(\frac{t}{\sin^2 t} - \cot t\right)e^{-t\cot t} dt$, we obtain
$$
\int \sin t\left(\frac{t}{\sin^2 t} - \cot t\right)e^{-t\cot t} dt = \sin t e^{-t\cot t} - \int \cos t e^{-t\cot t}dt
$$

Thus, $$\int \frac{t}{\sin t}e^{-t\cot t} dt = \sin t e^{-t\cot t} + C$$